# Best way to use a PostgreSQL database as a simple key value store

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, berkeley-db, key-value

I am being required to use a postgreSQL database and it will replace my current use of berkeleyDB. Although; I realize this is not an ideal situation, it is beyond my control.

So the question is... If you were required to make postgreSQL into a key value store how would you go about doing this, while making it as efficient as possible?

My values are byte arrays and my key's are strings, I could impose some restrictions on the lengths of these strings.

I assume I should use a blob for my value and primary key column holding the key, but as I am just venturing into this journey I am curious if anyone in the stack overflow community has done this, or if there are any specific 'gotchas' I should look out for.

Comment: What does those byte arrays actually represent? File contents? Serialized objects? Others?

Comment: They are actually serialized actionscript objects sent to a server... but the server code does not know or care what is in them.

And yes, I agree this is somewhat absurd, to use a relational database as a key value store. But some of the advantages of using the database are still maintained, such as efficient file io, encryption, user access restrictions, etc... So is it really that crazy?

Comment: Yes. http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores/

Comment: Thanks for the link... I would certainly like to use a true key value store if possible. I am not sure if any of these are approved to be used in a department of defense project, and trying to get them approved is a concern as it is not a timely task. I will do a bit more searching.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The extension in Postgresql to properly do this is called hstore.  It works in a similar fashion as you would expect other key-value store systems.   Just load the extension.  The syntax is unique but if you have ever used redis or mongo you will get it quickly.  Don't make it harder than it is.  I understand, we often don't get to pick our tools and have to make do.
Here is the document page:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

Comment: Here is how to load the extension.  You will need to be a DBA or superuser.
CREATE EXTENSION HSTORE;

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use JSON or JSONB with a unique hash index on the key.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE key_values (
    key uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    value jsonb
);

CREATE INDEX idx_key_values ON key_values USING hash (key);
```

Some queries

```
SELECT * FROM key_values WHERE key = '1cfc4dbf-a1b9-46b3-8c15-a03f51dde891';
Time: 0.514 ms
postgres=# SELECT * FROM key_values WHERE key = '1cfc4dbf-a1b9-46b3-8c15-a03f51dde890';
Time: 1.747 ms

postgres=# do $$
begin
for r in 1..1000 loop
INSERT INTO key_values (value)
VALUES ('{"somelarge_json": "bla"}');
end loop;
end;
$$;
DO
Time: 58.327 ms
```

You can't run efficient range queries like with B-tree, but it should have better  read/write performance. Index should be about 60% smaller.

Answer (score 4):

If you are forced to use relational database, I would suggest to try to find structure in your data to take advantage of the fact, since you forgo the advantage of speed you got with unstructured data and key-value store. The more structure you find, the better advantage you get out of your predicament. Even if you only find structure in the keys.

Also consider if you will only need sequential or random access to your data and in which ratio and structure your database by this requirement. Are you going to do queries on your values by type for example? Each of those questions could have effect on how you structure your database.

One specific consideration about blobs in postgresql they are internally represented as pg_largetable (loid:oid,pageno:int4,data:bytea). The size of the chunks is defined by LOBBLKSIZE, but typically 2k. So if you can use byte arrays in your table instead of blobs and limit size of your value/key pair under blocksize, you can avoid this indirection through second table. You could also increase the block size if you have access to configuration of the database.

I'd suggest to go looking for structure in data and patterns in data access and then ask your question again with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to store as a value ? Strings ? Ints ? Objects (e.g. serialized Java objects). A simple implementation would work with a 3 column table looking like:

```
NAME(VARCHAR)   TYPE(VARCHAR)   VALUE(VARCHAR)
```

(perhaps the TYPE is some enumeration). The above wouldn't work for binary data like serialised objects, though and perhaps you need a BLOB there.

Alternatively (and probably a *much* better idea), have you seen [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) ? You can back that with a database (via JDBC) and you can store properties such that you retrieve them thus:

```
// get a property called 'number'
Double double = config.getDouble("number");
Integer integer = config.getInteger("number");
```

That may save you a lot of grief in terms of implementation. You *may* have a problem with saving binary data, in that you'd have to serialise it prior to insertion and post-retrieval. But I've used this in the past for storing ints,doubles and serialised Java objects via XStream, so I can confirm it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It really should be dependant on what the key will be.  If it will always be a string under 255 characters, then use a Varchar as yoru PK and then use a blob (assuming a large value) for the value.  if it will always be a number, use int, etc.

In other words, need more info to really give you a good answer :)